# multi-line chart using D3 issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a multi-line chart using D3. I have written code but instead of showing two lines, only one line is coming and I am unable to figure out the reason for the this issue.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var data = [{
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "a"
}, {
  data: [
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
    ["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]
  ],
  label: "b"
}]


var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  });

var ary = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);
});

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(c) {
    return d3.min(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  }),
  d3.max(data, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.data, function(v) {
      return v[1];
    });
  })
]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "series");

series.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });
```

```css
text.inner-circle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
text.inner-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong.

[Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5H7mXUibdhSmA92J0Pi?p=preview)

Comment: Why you don't use a csv file for your data?

Comment: @Giordano: because backend sends data in this format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing a 'return'

```
x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));
```

should be

```
x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));
```

Comment: Thank You for pointing that out but still only one line is coming, instead of two. Please can you me what else i am doing wrong?

Comment: ah, you have got two lines, it's just that your two data sets are the same so one line's on top of the other.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the parseDate value when computing the domain.

```
x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/jt5nnx5h/

Comment: Thank You for pointing that out but still only one line is coming, instead of two lines. Please can you me what else i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited the question, please take a look. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the values in your data, you will see that you have two lines there.

Also try variegating your colors for your lines to better distinguish them like so:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();

series.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.data);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but this is already resolved. Please can you help me with my next issue -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962135/grouped-bar-chart-using-d3-issue Thank You again

Comment: While I am working on your next issue, a thumbs up would be nice ;)