# grouped Bar chart using D3 grid issue and console errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a grouped bar chart using D3. I have written code but bar charts are not showing properly and I am unable to figure out the reason for the this issue. Please see the code attached in this post.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var data = [{
  "data": [
    [
      "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
      1.41818181818182
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
      1.90661764705882
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
      1.66764705882353
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
      1.51691176470588
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
      1.40955882352941
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
      1.46323529411765
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
      1.48308823529412
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
      1.89384615384615
    ]
  ],
  "label": "a"
}, {
  "data": [
    [
      "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
      4.98701298701299
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
      5.0
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
      4.94852941176471
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
      4.91176470588235
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
      4.81617647058824
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
      5.0
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
      4.94117647058824
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
      4.96969696969697
    ]
  ],
  "label": "b"
}];


var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .9);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x).tickSize(0)
  .orient("bottom").innerTickSize(-height).outerTickSize(0)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left").innerTickSize(-width).outerTickSize(0);

var ary = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);
});

x.domain(ary[0].map(function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  console.log(d.y0 + d.y); //This is NaN = Not a number
  //return d.y0 + d.y;
  return d[1]; //returns grid lines if that is what you want
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "layer")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });

layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.data;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    console.log(d[1]);
    return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);
```

```css
text.inner-circle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
text.inner-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong. [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5H7mXUibdhSmA92J0Pi?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got your grid to show.

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  console.log(d.y0 + d.y); //This is NaN = Not a number
  //return d.y0 + d.y;
  return d[1]; //returns grid lines if that is what you want
})]);
```

Also address this part of your code:

```
layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.data;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    console.log(d[1]);
    return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);
```

With the above fixes to your code, I am seeing your rects and not errors. However, you have some css fixes to address as your bars are off of the x axes. There is also quite a bit of code missing for the grouping of your data.

Here is [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152) of a grouped bar chart. In looking at this example I see that you do have a way of distinguishing an x0 and x1 (first and second group). You will need to add this into your code to get to the next group of rectangles.

Comment: @ The second part of your code, doesn't creates the grouped bar chart properly. One series of bar charts are going down passing the x-axis and the other series of bar charts are up in the middle. Please suggest to a better way to fix this

Comment: I am working on that. How about an incentive? Got rid of your errors and got your grids to show.

Comment: I am really grateful to You for fixing the errors and showing grids. Ok, i am posting one more question related to new alignment issue.

Comment: Conocolato: link of new question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962560/grouped-bar-chart-using-d3-alignment-issue Thank you again for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors you are getting are:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
```

Clearly what this is saying is that you're doing math wrong somewhere (NaN = not a number).

The offending section of code:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {
  return y(d.y + d.y0);
})
.attr("height", function(d) {
  return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
})
```

So, what's wrong here? Well, dump a few `console.log()` statements into the functions and you'll quickly see you're missing the attributes you're trying to access.

If you look closely at the code right above the offending math:

```
.data(function(d) {
  return d.data;
})
```

You've given [`d3.selection.data(\[values\[, key\]\])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) method a key function, but you didn't actually give it any data (well, any data you care about: technically the function definition itself is a data object, which is why the method doesn't complain).

What you want:

```
.data(data) // or maybe you meant .data(ary)
```

Comment: FYI .data(ary) returns error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", so I do not think he meant that.