# multi/grouped Bar chart using D3 alignment issue

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am creating a grouped bar chart using D3. I have written code and bar charts are showing but not properly. Some bar are going below the x-axis and other are at the top of the graph instead starting from 0. I am unable to figure out the reason for the this issue.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var data = [{
  "data": [
    [
      "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
      1.41818181818182
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
      1.90661764705882
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
      1.66764705882353
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
      1.51691176470588
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
      1.40955882352941
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
      1.46323529411765
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
      1.48308823529412
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
      1.89384615384615
    ]
  ],
  "label": "a"
}, {
  "data": [
    [
      "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
      4.98701298701299
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
      5.0
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
      4.94852941176471
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
      4.91176470588235
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
      4.81617647058824
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
      5.0
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
      4.94117647058824
    ],
    [
      "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
      4.96969696969697
    ]
  ],
  "label": "b"
}];


var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .9);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x).tickSize(0)
  .orient("bottom").innerTickSize(-height).outerTickSize(0)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left").innerTickSize(-width).outerTickSize(0);

var ary = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);
});

x.domain(ary[0].map(function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  console.log(d.y0 + d.y); //This is NaN = Not a number
  //return d.y0 + d.y;
  return d[1]; //returns grid lines if that is what you want
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "layer")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i);
  });

layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.data;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(parseDate.parse(d[0]));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    console.log(d[1]);
    return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);
```

```css
text.inner-circle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
text.inner-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: I am using this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 as a guide.

Comment: @Mr. Concolato I am also using same as guide but out data format differs that is why i am facing issues

Answer (score 1):

You are missing this:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {
  return height - y(d[1]); //<-- offset y position from height
})
```

In addition, you aren't taking into account where to group your bars.  Simple fix is to place them side-by-side:

```
  ...
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
    // j is the group
    if (j === 0)
      return x(parseDate.parse(d[0])) - x.rangeBand() / 2;
    else
      return x(parseDate.parse(d[0])) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
  })
  ...
```

---

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
        text.inner - circle {
      font - weight: 400;
      font - size: 12 px;
      text - transform: uppercase;
    }
    text.inner - text {
      font - weight: 400;
      font - size: 36 px;
      font - family: 'Metric Regular', 'Metric';
      text - align: center;
      font - style: normal;
      text - transform: uppercase;
    }
    path {
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke - width: 2;
      fill: none;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: grey;
      stroke - width: 2;
      shape - rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .grid.tick {
        stroke: lightgrey;
        stroke - opacity: 0.7;
        shape - rendering: crispEdges;
      }
      .grid path {
        stroke - width: 0;
      }
    
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var z = d3.scale.category20c();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

    var data = [{
      "data": [
        [
          "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
          1.41818181818182
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
          1.90661764705882
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
          1.66764705882353
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
          1.51691176470588
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
          1.40955882352941
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
          1.46323529411765
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
          1.48308823529412
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
          1.89384615384615
        ]
      ],
      "label": "a"
    }, {
      "data": [
        [
          "2016-01-21T01:20:00.000Z",
          4.98701298701299
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T02:28:00.000Z",
          5.0
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T03:36:00.000Z",
          4.94852941176471
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T04:44:00.000Z",
          4.91176470588235
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T05:52:00.000Z",
          4.81617647058824
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T07:00:00.000Z",
          5.0
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T08:08:00.000Z",
          4.94117647058824
        ],
        [
          "2016-01-21T09:16:00.000Z",
          4.96969696969697
        ]
      ],
      "label": "b"
    }];


    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .9);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x).tickSize(0)
      .orient("bottom").innerTickSize(-height).outerTickSize(0)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left").innerTickSize(-width).outerTickSize(0);

    var ary = [];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      ary.push(d.data);
    });

    x.domain(ary[0].map(function(d) {
      return parseDate.parse(d[0]);
    }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
      console.log(d.y0 + d.y); //This is NaN = Not a number
      //return d.y0 + d.y;
      return d[1]; //returns grid lines if that is what you want
    })]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return z(i);
      });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.data;
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
        if (j === 0)
          return x(parseDate.parse(d[0])) - x.rangeBand() / 2;
        else
          return x(parseDate.parse(d[0])) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return height -y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]); //Note this is returning data
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 1);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```